# jquery image slider with image strip dragging

Tags: jquery

I want to create a image strip slider using jquery. I have used jcarousel plugin for my image gallery and light box plugin to get preview of selected image. Now, my task is when any of the image is selected i can drag to either side. i.e I can select the image and drag to any direction within that image container. 
If any one can help me on this???

> **Update from comment:**

```
$( "img" ).Draggable({ connectToSortable: 'ul#mycarousel', axis: 'x'}); 
//getter 
var connectToSortable = $("img" ).Draggable( "option", "connectToSortable" ); 
//setter 
$( "img" ).Draggable( "option", "connectToSortable", 'ul#mycarousel' );
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide us with a demo or some code. It's harder to help you when you want us to read your mind :P

Comment: okayy,

$( "img" ).Draggable({ connectToSortable: 'ul#mycarousel', axis: 'x'});
 
 //getter
 var connectToSortable = $("img" ).Draggable( "option", "connectToSortable" );
 //setter
 $( "img" ).Draggable( "option", "connectToSortable", 'ul#mycarousel' );

I'm able to drag individual elements inside my image strip but i want to drag whole image strip. 
Hope u got...
Thanks